# Kafka JDBC sink - Is there way to store the Kafka topic value as one column value in table?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

let's say
key = 1234
value = {"name": "Dave Smith", "place": "USA", "occupation": "doctor"}

I am looking for the sink connector to store whole value as Json String into table column.

tried this

```
"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
"value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable":"false"
```

Comment: why don't you consider using `StringConverter` for the value as well?

Comment: @KarimTawfik That will fail because JDBC Sink requires a Struct type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the database table ahead of time to only have one JSON column.

See examples here - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/46#issuecomment-1135209669